# Howler.js - referencing and triggering files from an array/for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, audio, howler.js

I'm trying to use an array and for-loop to index and name some Howls and Howl trigger buttons.

I've referenced this question for what I'm trying to achieve: [Howler - Random sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403203/javascript-and-howler-js-how-to-choose-a-random-sound)
The difference with mine is that it's without the random aspect plus I've added some method calls.

I'm adding the buttons used to trigger the Howls into the loop and that's where it seems to be failing - namely when the buttons are clicked.

Console reports the following when either button is clicked:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`
Specifically referring to this: `sounds[i].play();` or `sounds[i].pause();`

Here's the JS:

```
var sounds = ['sound1', 'sound2'];
var howls = {};
for (var i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) {
    howls[sounds[i]] = new Howl({
        urls: ['http://powellian.com/assets/audio/' + sounds[i] + '.mp3', 'http://powellian.com/assets/audio/' + sounds[i] + '.ogg'],
        volume: 1,
        onplay: function() {
            console.log('Playing: ' + sounds[i]);
            $(sounds[i]).removeClass('static').addClass('playing');
            $(sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-play').addClass('hide');
            $(sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-pause').removeClass('hide');
        },
        onpause: function() {
            console.log('Paused: ' + sounds[i]);
            $(sounds[i]).removeClass('playing').addClass('paused');
            $(sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-play').removeClass('hide');
            $(sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-pause').addClass('hide');
        },
        onend: function() {
            console.log('Finished: ' + sounds[i]);
            $(sounds[i]).removeClass().addClass('static');
            $(sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-play').removeClass('hide');
            $(sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-pause').addClass('hide');
        }
    });

    // PLAY btn
    $('#' + sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-play').on('click', function (e) {
        sounds[i].play();
    });
    // PAUSE btn
   $('#' + sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-pause').on('click', function (e) {
        sounds[i].pause();
    });
}
```

I had a non-array/for-loop version working fine with 2 Howls, and the add/remove class stuff works fine so please ignore that.

I will eventually be generating 16 Howls from the array.

Here's a fiddle which includes the markup structure: [Howler Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dxshpj7/)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that I see here:

1. You are referencing the variable `i` inside the `click` handler without maintaining scope. Because of this, it will always see `i` as the last value. You could use `bind` as one way of fixing this:

`$('#' + sounds[i] + ' span.ascii-play').on('click', function (i2, e) {
    sounds[i2].play();
}.bind(null, i));`

2. You are trying to call `play` on `sounds`, which isn't holding the reference to the `Howl` object. You should be calling `play` on `howls[sounds[i2]]` instead.

EDIT: In this case it is just easier to use a `forEach`, so I've updated your fiddle to do that and fix the scoping issues here: http://jsfiddle.net/zmjz7sf3/1/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated as per your comments and can see what you're saying re the incorrect object reference and function scoping. However, the scoping in this example I don't fully understand tbh.

The good news is that there aren't any console errors, but it's still not playing. I've updated the Fiddle to reflect your comments, also adding links to external audio files, missing before.

Is there anything glaringly wrong there? [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2dxshpj7/1/)

Comment: Scrub the last comment as I've got the audio playing now with that advice, thanks!
However, the play/pause hide/reveal classes aren't working for what i guess is the same scoping issue. I've had a bash at applying the same .bind() approach but it's returning 'undefined' in the console.log. Will continue hitting that as/when i can, will be a bit intermittent though.
Here's an [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2dxshpj7/9/)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that and .forEach() is so clearly the way to go with this. I've got the other stuff running - add/remove classes etc. Many thanks for your help on that.

Comment: Now there's another weird offshoot problem in that `.pause()` has stopped working properly. Will tinker but may need to get another fiddle going for that as I can't reproduce it properly. But what's happening is when Pause button is clicked the 'audible' audio stops, but it is still running silently. The `console.log` for `onend` reports when it _actually_ ends. Will work on it and check back here if no joy. Thanks so far though!