# Howler.js - pause method only Muting howls, not actually Pausing them

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, howler.js

This is part of an ongoing question: [triggering files from an array/for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212594/)

I'm having an issue with Howls not actually pausing, but in effect 'muting'. The howls, when click-paused do mute but continue running silently. I've tried using `.stop()` but am getting the same result.

I am using `onend` property which works and shows that `.pause()` method isn't working. When pause/play is clicked repeatedly it all gets pretty messy!

Before the howls and related control buttons were scripted from an array the pause worked perfectly. It's since the array was used that the pause method has stopped working properly.

Here's a: [fiddle of the current pause issue](https://jsfiddle.net/8sxfc2Lt/1/) (console logs are working there)

Here's the js:

```
var sounds = ['sound1', 'sound2'];
var howls = {};
sounds.forEach(function(sound){
    howls[sound] = new Howl({
        urls: ['http://powellian.com/assets/audio/' + sound + '.mp3', 'http://powellian.com/assets/audio/' + sound + '.ogg'],
        volume: 1,
        onplay: function() {
            console.log('PLAYING: ' + sound);
            $('#' + sound).removeClass('static').addClass('PLAYING');
            $('#' + sound + ' span.play').addClass('hide');
            $('#' + sound + ' span.pause').removeClass('hide');
        },
        onpause: function() {
            console.log('PAUSED: ' + sound);
            $('#' + sound).removeClass('PLAYING').addClass('PAUSED');
            $('#' + sound + ' span.play').removeClass('hide');
            $('#' + sound + ' span.pause').addClass('hide');
        },
        onend: function() {
            console.log('ENDED: ' + sound);
            $('#' + sound).removeClass().addClass('static');
            $('#' + sound + ' span.play').removeClass('hide');
            $('#' + sound + ' span.pause').addClass('hide');
        }
    });

    // PLAY btn
    $('#' + sound + ' span.play').click(function () {
        howls[sound].play();
    });
    // PAUSE btn
    $('#' + sound + ' span.pause').click(function () {
        howls[sound].pause();
    });
});
```

For the record this is using Howler v1.1.29. Tried it with v2.0 but that won't work at all for various other reasons (e.g. won't load the array - I don't need 2.0 but would be willing to run tests with this issue if it helps at all).

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean 2.0 wouldn't load the array? Did you change `urls` to `src`?

Comment: No has always been `urls` but have just re bower updated locally and 2.0 is now working fine albeit with the same problem listed here. Had updated before and error msg was that array couldn't load. I've left the fiddle with 1.1.29 as not sure which 2.0-beta* link to use from cdnjs

Comment: Hopefully to clarify the issue: when `pause` is hit the sound mutes but still effectively runs silently and fires `onend` - if you quickly fire `play` again it just leads to `onend` being fired twice. This happens for as many times as you fire `play`, with the sound actually playing/layering, not pausing. The console.logs illustrate it. Hope that helps, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - my bad but with v2.0 I didn't realise `urls` needed to be changed to `src` so did that and it's all working fine.

On local version I added another audio file to the array and pausing and onend all work perfectly. Thanks for your advice!

Here's an [updated fiddle using 2.0.0-beta14](https://jsfiddle.net/8sxfc2Lt/3/)